# PHP not decoding a JSON object created with Javascript. Error ALWAYS returns 4

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to create a mapping of key and value pairs in javascript. I create an object and paste it into a hidden textarea, so i can collect it with PHP and decode the object and eventually save it to a database. The data comes in a JSON format, but i'm unable to decode it as a JSON Object in PHP. json_last_error() always returns a 4 and i have no idea why.

Here i fill my onject in Javascript:

```
finalMapping =  databaseMappingList.reduce(function(finalMapping, field, index) {
    finalMapping [fileMappingList[index]] = field;
    return finalMapping;
  }, {})
```

which works fine. Then i paste it into a txtarea:

```
$('#txtarea').val(JSON.stringify(finalMapping ));
```

i get the following output, when i echo $_POST["txtarea"]:

```
{"a":"a","b":"b","c":"c"}
```

which i assume is a valid JSON string. hen i use json_decode($_POST["txtarea"]), i get NULL and when i echo json_last_error(), i get 4. hat am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try `var_dump($_POST['txtarea']);` instead of echo for debugging.

Comment: post  a comment for one line answer

Comment: i get string(4467)  {"a":"a","b":"b", ....} as it's pretty long

Comment: check the syntax of this or paste the complete string; error code 4 = JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX